# Comic/Manga from early 2000's: thief-like guy with a snarky fairy companion, accompanied by a female mage and a tank

Tags: story-identification, comics, anime, manga, sword-and-sorcery

It's been a long time since I've read it, so the details are a bit hazy. There might have even been an anime, but I honestly can't say. What I remember most is the beginning of it, because it stuck out so much. Anyway. It's a swords and sorcery type story. Medieval tech level. Set entirely in a fantasy world (meaning I don't recognize any sites or anything from our world in it).

It starts off having the heroes facing off against the big bad. I think he was a lich-type with heavy-looking armour. And the big bad essentially kills them all off one by one, making the whole story seem like a 'life flashing before your eyes' type retelling.

The next thing you know, the main protagonist is under a tree with his fairy buzzing about, not more than a chapter before he meets the second member of the party.

I don't remember too much, other than this, because the opening was so unique that it stuck with me through the years. But if I recall correctly, the main protag was a thief-like guy with either a dagger or a short-ish sword, and the girl was I think a mage-type or a healer (light armour if not full on cloth). I believe there were two others. The tank and the mage, but I honestly don't remember anything about them.

The fairy was a bit sarcastic, too. I remember loving that one so bad. I think female, but honestly I was more interested in the snarky banter.

I'm itching to go back and read it (or watch it if there really was a show).

Edit (addition for comments):

- No, it most definitely isn't *Berserk*. The main protag of this story was young-ish. Late teens maybe.
- Yes, it was drawn in a manga style, so it's possible it was originally Japanese. But I remember the story element better than the art style. I know it wasn't American, originally (hence why I said there might have been an anime, simply because of the way the faces were drawn), but I don't remember the artist (I usually don't).
- Art style wasn't anything out there, or all that unique for the time. The faces (as I said) were all typical for Japanese artists (though I've read western comics that mimicked this). It wasn't overly stylized, I think more of a 'realistic' approach.
- I can't remember too well how the characters looked. And honestly, I don't remember if it was in colour or black and white (as I said, it's the story that stood out most to me)
- I read most comics off a website in those days. So it was digital. Scanlation is possible, and was common for most comics/manga I read at the time.
- Other than the fairy, all party members seemed human (this IS fantasy, so I say that with hesitance). Is any had pointy ears, I don't remember.

But that's basically all I remember. Or at least remember well enough that I am confident enough to say so. I've seen a LOT of shows and read a LOT of comics/manga since then, and I don't want to make people think it can't be 'that show' because 'this detail doesn't match'.

Comment: Was it in English? [Fairy Companion](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/FairyCompanion) (link to TvTropes) is actually a fairly-common plot device.

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas I know I read it in English. If it was originally in English is the better question.(checking link to see if I can find it there)

Comment: Just want to confirm this (if possible): the title mentioned "comic", but it seems you got *Berserk* as a suggestion from the comment, which is actually a manga (Japanese comic). You also mentioned "anime", not "cartoon". Perhaps this is a bit nitpicky, but could you clarify whether it's actually a (Western) comic or a manga, perhaps by art style? Also, do you remember the races of other characters? Finally, are you reading it on a physical/official digital book, not scanlation? (this is to reduce the scope to licensed series)

Comment: The story does not quite match, but the characters resemble those of French comic book (later traduced into English) [_The Legendaries_](https://www.google.fr/search?q=the+legendaries+jovenia).

Comment: @AndrewT. Updating my question to address as much of your observations as possible. Sorry that my memory of it is so sketchy. It's mostly that opening bit that really stuck out for me, and I don't want other similar series/stories to blend in with it, since I've seen/read a lot with the same basic setting.

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas I've gone over the list. Nothing TT_TT

Comment: Could it have been a video game?

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas Is it possible a game was made based on it? Yes. But no, the story I'm talking about was a visual medium. I remember the comic style layout, and as I said, it's possible they made an anime out of it. But nothing I've searched has given me any leads.

Answer (score 2):

I am wondering if you are not looking for *[Saga](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saga_(comics))*, a comic that came out in 2012 which is basically told from the eyes of the child of two warring species.

> The series is heavily influenced by *Star Wars* and is based on ideas
>   Vaughan conceived both as a child and as a parent. It depicts a
>   husband and wife, Alana and Marko, from long-warring extraterrestrial
>   races, fleeing authorities from both sides of a galactic war as they
>   struggle to care for their daughter, Hazel, who is born in the
>   beginning of the series and who occasionally narrates the series as an
>   unseen adult.

[image: Saga cover]

Comment: I've edited out the link to the comic site. I'm pretty sure it's unlicenced and hence naughty.

Comment: I second what @Valorum said. This site and its network have some pretty explicit NSFW ads that pop up when you open it. Please link to more neutral sites in the future :) (Goodreads, Wikipedia, ComicVine etc)

Comment: Thank you for this, I'll probably look into it more, but no, this wasn't it.